# Android Studio's menus are very lagging, hardly usable

Tags: linux, android-studio, ubuntu, menu, virtualbox

I run Android Studio 4.0 on Xubuntu 20.04 as a guest of VirtualBox running on MacBook Pro host.  The menus (from File, Edit, etc, as well as from within window), though pop up immediately once pressed, have very slow reaction when mouse moves inside the menu, taking 5-20 seconds to get an item highlighted.  No other programs on the system have such problem.  I don't believe it's a system resource issue as editing and build processes run through fine and it's got 2 cores and 4GB RAM.  Generally the system has at least 1GB RAM free when Android Studio is running.  And I set "Power Save Mode" on Android Studio.

I googled but found no mentioning about the issue.  Any idea what's wrong?

======
Update:
I installed Android Studio in two ways: by directly downloading the linux.tar.gz file from developer.android.com, and by installing from snap store.  The problem is largely the same: menu items not responsive.  Surprised no other people have this issue.

++++++
This is a horrible problem I can't find a solution.  Menu reaction to mouse move very lagging.  No one has this problem?

---

OK, did more testing.  It turns out the culprit is VirtualBox 6.1.x.  I tried VBox 5.2.44 and 6.0.24 (have to use VBoxVGA): day and night difference from 6.1.14, with 5.2 at its heyday and 6.0 a bit behind.  Basically 6.1 is not usable, even with VBoxVGA driver, though programs other than Android Studio are not terribly slow with 6.1, some graphics programs hangs up the GUI entirely.  I will now stick with 6.0.24.

BTW, where is everybody?  Am I just talking to myself?

++++++++++++
Well, VBox 6.0 with VBoxVGA does not make it fast outright.  It has to do with how one sets the scalefactor of the display.  If set at exactly 200%, then it's fast.  If it's off, like 195%, then it's slow.  This might be the same issue with 6.1 as I had set it at 198%, but I have not double checked this on 6.1.  I will stick with 6.0 as VBoxVGA still remains a legal choice, on 6.1, VBoxVGA is marked as not legal.

++++++++++++
OK, tried VBox 6.1.14 again.  It's actually not worse than 6.0.  The fundamental issue has to do with display scaling.  If scale factor is set to 100%, all have no problem in performance, regardless of VBoxVGA or VMSVGA.  The best solution/workaround so far is in Applications folder of Mac to set "Open in low resolution" for VirtualBox (on getinfo popup), then in VBox set the guest to scale to 100%.  This way, when the guest is started, it uses the same resolution as the Mac.  The highest resolution my MacBook Pro 13 retina provides is 1680x1050.  If this is not high enough, there is an open source app here (https://github.com/aryamccarthy) that allows one to set higher resolutions on the mac.  I set it at 2048x1280.

So, I am coming in a circle back to VBox 6.1.14, and it's all set good.  A key reason for me prefer 6.1 vs 6.0 is that horizontal scroll is supported with 6.1.

Answer (score 0):

++++++++++++ Well, VBox 6.0 with VBoxVGA does not make it fast outright. It has to do with how one sets the scalefactor of the display. If set at exactly 200%, then it's fast. If it's off, like 195%, then it's slow. This might be the same issue with 6.1 as I had set it at 198%, but I have not double checked this on 6.1. I will stick with 6.0 as VBoxVGA still remains a legal choice, on 6.1, VBoxVGA is marked as not legal.

++++++++++++ OK, tried VBox 6.1.14 again. It's actually not worse than 6.0. The fundamental issue has to do with display scaling. If scale factor is set to 100%, all have no problem in performance, regardless of VBoxVGA or VMSVGA. The best solution/workaround so far is in Applications folder of Mac to set "Open in low resolution" for VirtualBox (on getinfo popup), then in VBox set the guest to scale to 100%. This way, when the guest is started, it uses the same resolution as the Mac. The highest resolution my MacBook Pro 13 retina provides is 1680x1050. If this is not high enough, there is an open source app here (https://github.com/aryamccarthy) that allows one to set higher resolutions on the mac. I set it at 2048x1280.

So, I am coming in a circle back to VBox 6.1.14, and it's all set good. A key reason for me prefer 6.1 vs 6.0 is that horizontal scroll is supported with 6.1.